# AddDllDirectory interferes with subsequent LoadLibraryExW

Tags: c++, winapi, kernel32

In our application we have a special structure for the dll search path.
Due to an update of a third party library, the resolving of dlls is now broken.
Attempts to fix the search path with `AddDllDirectory` resulted in unexpected problems.

`MyApp.exe` is a `C++/MFC`-application and uses `Managed#1.dll`, which in turn calls a native dll.
Furthermore, it needs `MyNativeDll.dll` which is installed in a different folder:

```
Folder structure:
Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe
                   \Managed#1.dll                  
                   \x86\Native#1.dll
Program Files\MyDll\MyNativeDll.dll
                   \Managed#2.dll
                   \x86\Native#2.dll
```

The original problem we had, was that `Native#2.dll` was not found (this dll was added in an update of a third party library in `Managed#2.dll`).
So I added the following to the `DllMain` of `MyNativeDll`:

```
MyNativeDll.dll::DllMain
{
    [...]
    SetDefaultDllDirectories(LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS);
    AddDllDirectory("[...]Program Files\MyDll\x86");
}
```

After this, `Native#2.dll` is loaded as expected.

**But**: Now when `MyApp.exe` loads `Managed#1.dll`, this call fails, as `Managed#1.dll` fails to load `Native#1.dll`.
The problematic call now is (the following is in some 3rd party library):

```
Managed#1.dll::Foo()
{
    LoadLibraryExW("Native#1.dll", NULL, 0);  //<-- This searches in the wrong path
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory), `AddDllDirectory` should only add some directory to the search path.

How can `AddDllDirectory` cause a latter call to `LoadLibraryExW` to fail?

Comment: I'm not sure why `Native#1.dll` would ever have been found, given that it's in a sub-directory. Normal DLL search paths includes the program folder, but not sub-directories.

Comment: *"How can `AddDllDirectory` cause a latter call to `LoadLibraryExW` to fail?"* - By forcing the system to load a module from a location it otherwise wouldn't. If a dependency is inaccessible from that location added to the search path, the request to load the module fails.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Thanks for the hint. I had a look into the source code of the 3rd party dll. There is some elaborate code that determines the "x86"-subpath, and (correctly) loads the library from there.
I suppose, the actual problem appears shortly after, when this library tries to load its own dependencies (`Native#1.dll` actually is 20 dlls) , and does not search relative to its own path anymore (see my answer below). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out, that the problematic call was not `AddDllDirectory()`, but the previous `SetDefaultDllDirectories()`.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-setdefaultdlldirectories) lists a number of flags (`LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_APPLICATION_DIR`, `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32`, `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_USER_DIRS`) and states that `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS` is a combination of those three.

Anyways, there is another option `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR`, which is not mentioned in this list.
So the call to

```
SetDefaultDllDirectories(LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS);
```

effectively removed `LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR` from the search path.
Replacing the above with

```
SetDefaultDllDirectories(LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS | LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR);
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR is an invalid flag for SetDefaultDllDirectories function. You can check that result of such call will be 0, which indicates that there is an issue. You can retrieve the error code with GerLastError and it will be 87 (The parameter is incorrect.)

Comment: After more than 3 years (and in a different company) it is a bit hard to tell... Then, I analysed the dll-search paths with sysinternals process monitor, and observed the correct load behavior after this one-line fix. Anyways, the problem originated in a third-party dll, so the reason *why* the fix worked, might be a bit more complicated, than I desribed in the answer.